# cocos2d NDK Build Fail

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

When i am trying to  compile my cocos2d-x project in android it is giving me error

building native
NDK build mode: debug
Ndk build failed!

What i have done till now

I have tried all versions of NDK.I set it on my bash_profile file. but still getting same error. I am using the cocos2d -x 3.6 in mac.I have tried to create the blank new project as well but getting any solution. I have updated the local.properties file ndk.dir

[image]

Comment: Did you also run the `setup.py` in the cocos2d-x directory? What version of `Ant` do you have?

Comment: yes i did run setup.py actully i develop my project in ios, now i want to import that in android. My apache version is 1.9.4

Comment: Ant 1.9.4 should be fine. Did you also install `Android 6.0 (API 23)` via the [Android SDK manager](http://thelogbox.com/img/phonegap/android-manager.png)?

Comment: yes i installed the android studio with API 23

Comment: You could try forcing cocos console to use s specific API, just ass `--ap android-23`. But the fact it could not determine this by itself indicates a problem with your development environment. I could keep on guessing possible problems, but you should probably try to do the same as this person first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30409756/3931225